# Remove dnscrypt

Tags: 16.04, dns, mint, dnscrypt-proxy

I want to update DNScrypt with the latest (2.0.15) version. I run DNScrypt 1.6.1-1, but it seems to render Internet traffic unreliable. (Note, I run Mint 18.3 Linux Mint 18.3 "Sylvia" - KDE 64-bit i.e. Ubuntu xenial.

However, I am reading this from the DNScrypt [git-site](https://github.com/jedisct1/dnscrypt-proxy/wiki/Installation-Debian-Ubuntu):

> Do not upgrade from v1.x on Ubuntu Xenial. Instead first backup your
>   systemd units (service and socket) then remove the old version and
>   delete the systemd service file (keep the socket), then upgrade
>   (replace artful with xenial in ppa sources.list). If you don't remove
>   the old systemd unit service, the upgrade will not replace it and the
>   new version will attempt to be started using the old systemd unit,
>   which will fail.

As a non-technical person, how do I

1. backup the systemd units (service and socket)
2. remove the old version
3. delete the systemd service file (keep the socket),
4. then upgrade (replace artful with xenial in ppa sources.list).

Re the 4th point, I assume this can be done via

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shevchuk/dnscrypt-proxy && \
sudo apt update && \
sudo apt install dnscrypt-proxy
```

However, the first 3 points look totally cryptic to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you run `dpkg-query -L dnscrypt-proxy`, you'll see file listed under `/lib/systemd/system`.  Those are your dnsproxy systemd files.  I'm not sure why the instructions mention to backup the files because it never says to do anything further with the backups.  Here's how you could save them to `/root`: `sudo cp -a /lib/systemd/system/dnscrypt-proxy* /root`
2. Remove the old package by doing `sudo apt remove dnscrypt-proxy`
3. Delete the service files: `sudo rm -v /lib/systemd/system/dnscrypt-proxy*.service`
4. You shouldn't need to do this because `add-apt-repository` knows you're on Xenial and will configure appropriately.  You can check by viewing the ppa sources: `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*dnscrypt*.list`.

Comment: Why the -1 for my question?

Comment: If I down voted it, it was by accident. Is there a way to tell if I did that?  I thought anyone could down vote a question...

Comment: Dunno, it looks like a normal question to me. Maybe you can up-vote?